# Flask. Глобальная функция/переменная для templates

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

base.html

```
<body>
    {% for category in categories %}
        {{ category }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    categories = Category.query.all()
    return render_template('index.html', categories=categories)
```

Куда можно вынести следующий код, что бы переменная categories была доступна в base.html?

```
categories = Category.query.all()
```

base.html вызывается только через {% extends 'base.html %}, соотвественно хочется избавиться от передачи переменной categories во все шаблоны вызываемые в функциях routes (render_template).

---

Нашёл решение, но оно мне не нравится:

```
def get_categories():
    return Category.query.all()


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', categories=get_categories())
```

Вданном решении приходится передавать каждый раз categories в шаблон. От этого хотелось бы избавиться.

Еще вижу вариант вызова функции внутри base.html, но на мой взгляд это костыль (возможно ошибаюсь).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__init__.py`

```
@app.context_processor
def utility_processor():
    def get_categories():
        return Category.query.all()

    return dict(categories=get_categories())
```

Comment: Вариант с `@app.context_processor` выглядит красиво :)

Answer (score 1):

[Можно добавить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7226047/5909792) свою функцию в шаблон через добавление функции в глобальные переменные `jinja`, что в `flask` используется для шаблонов.

Пример:

```
def clever_function():
    return u'HELLO'

app.jinja_env.globals.update(clever_function=clever_function)
```

и в вашем шаблоне вызывайте ее как `{{ clever_function() }}`